# ¿Por qué no puedo usar una variable declarada en otro metodo?

Tags: c#, asp.net

¿Por qué me arroja error que la variable `DIR_Id` en `CrearEncuesta_Onclick()` no existe?

El código es el siguiente, no es total es sólo para dar la idea, me gustaría saber porque no reconoce la variable `int DIR_Id;` declarada antes y cómo se podría solucionar.

```
public void getData(string user)
{
 int DIR_Id;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyStringWeb"].ConnectionString;
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            var cmmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CLI_Id FROM vw_DatosCliente WHERE Username=@Username", conn);
            cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Session["Username"].ToString());
            System.Data.DataTable dtddl = new System.Data.DataTable();
            dtddl.Load(cmmd.ExecuteReader());
            CLI_Id = Convert.ToString(dtddl.Rows[0]["CLI_Id"]);
            DIR_Id = Convert.ToInt32(dtddl.Rows[0]["CLI_Id"]);

        }
}

 protected void CrearEncuesta_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         labelClienteID.Text = DIR_Id; 
    }
```

Comment: Yo haría una clase y declararía la variable dentro de la misma. Asñi podrías acceder desde cualquier método a ella. Si declaras una variable dentro de un método, esta variable será visible solo para el método.

Comment: Muchas gracias compa por tu comentario, así está más claro, ahora sólo voy a ver como creo la famosa clase.

Comment: @Vulpex la clase ya la tienes creada por defecto, es donde estan contenidos tus metodos getData y CrearEncuesta_Onclick

Comment: Sigo sin comprender compa, tendrías unos minutos para orientarme por el chat y no extender los comentarios?
Porque yo ve que dice `public partial class contentPrivate_encuestaSatisfaccion : System.Web.UI.Page
{...` entonces como se agregaría o como se contruiría la clase? corte y pegue debajo de esta linea la variable y me arrojó error, y buscando en me dicen que cree un archivo class  y luego llame la librería y ya me perdi...

Comment: No se como funciona el chat pero te pongo aqui un ejemplo:

public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page  \\esta es la clase
    {
        private int variable= 0; \\ esta variable esta disponible para todos los metodos de la clase
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Session.Abandon();
                Session.Clear();
            }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La variable esta declarada solo para el método getData por eso no es visible desde otro método, la deberías declarar para toda la clase.

http://csharp.com.es/ambito-de-las-variables/

Comment: Un poco de codigo no nos caeria mal ya que el link puede que no este diponibles despues un tiempo :). Excelente sitio por cierto. No lo conocia.